# SQL Query to VBA Array

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, recordset, vba

As the title suggests I am looking into different ways to store the contents of a query into an array. I have been experimenting with different varieties of doing this, but it seems to be that most of these ways are in correct in their output. This is of course do to my lack of understanding of how this is supposed to be appropriately done, so after a while of experimenting I have decided to ask whats the best approach for this? I will share with you some of my approaches thus far and you can see where my investigation has landed me.

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
MyArray = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)
```

This was *ok* yet this stored all the information vertically instead of horizontally. Is there a way to flip that? Would that be through the use of ReDim? Or is this due to the fact the rows are getting stored in array dimensions and thus they naturally vertical?

```
        Index = 0
        Do While Not rst.EOF
                ReDim Preserve MyArray(1, Index)
                MyArray(0, Index) = CStr(rst.Fields(0).Value)

                'Safety check to make sure the value isn't null (was having problems before)
                If rst.Fields(1).Value <> vbNullString Then
                    MyArray(1, Index) = CStr(rst.Fields(1).Value)
                End If
            Index = Index + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop

        sheet.Range("a1:ba10000").Value = MyArray
```

This again stored things vertically, but didnt output the records correctly, and in fact only pull the first two columns of info per record, the rest was output as #N/A#. I think I was closer with my original approach, but decided experimenting might land me somewhere.

Do you peeps have some suggestions or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be quicker to just dump the results to the sheet using:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

And then store the results of that dump (from the range) into an array. If it isn't vertical or horizontal like you like, a quick copy/paste-special transpose will make very quick work of it, before bringing it back into the array.

I'm only suggesting that since it seems like your recordset is rather large (2x10000), so iterating as you are doing is going to be time consuming, where dumping the results to the worksheet, manipulating, and picking them back up should be very very quick.

---

Update (many years later). Looks like it's possible to dump into an array. Something like:

```
Dim arr
rst.MoveFirst
arr = rst.GetRows
```

This would allow for programatic manipulation of the recordset (in the array) before shooting the data out to the workbook.

Comment: If you want the headers, paste to `"A2"` and add the following:                     `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                        Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, rst.Fields.Count))
                        For Each Cell1 In Range1
                            Cell1.Value = rst.Fields(Cell1.Column - 1).Name
                            Cell1.Font.Bold = True
                        Next Cell1
                    End With`

Comment: See I was doing that before and I am now in the experimental phase where I try and improve performance, but you make it sound like its "6 of one, half dozen of the other" where the trade offs dont really amount to much.

Comment: It seems sort of kludgey to dump the recordset into the worksheet, manipulate, and then pick it back up into your array to do whatever else you are going to do, but... your result set is large, and data transformation within a range is what Excel... excels at... So I would just let it do it's thing.

Comment: Yeah I get that but the thing i was trying to avoid was looping through fields for headers and then dumping recordset per sheet per workbook. Granted no biggy when there is only one recordset and its x-amount. It eats up time when you hitting multiple instances of large queries (My current full code does this about 20 times). I mean it takes 3-4 minutes and thats not bad... but you know how it goes - tinker for fun to see what you can do @JNevill

Comment: I'm all about tinkering. I'll refactor for hours to save a few lousy seconds. I just added to the answer with a function that I use to grab data from a DB and dump results (optionally with headers) to the workbook. And then an example where I use that function to grab data, dump it, bold the headers,  transpose the data, and stick the results in an array.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to what Im already using except for some fancy boldening you got going on there (though I will def save this example and compare notes). I guess here is some "preference" based questions: Why use ADODB versus DAO? Is there any real reason? I would like to legitimately understand why you would use one above the other, o if you have handy link id love some reading material. @JNevill

Comment: I use ADODB because I'm connecting to Teradata (and sometimes SQLServer and, every once in awhile, to an excel sheet) and it's what I feel comfortable with. It's fast, well supported, and feels more like a standard outside of Access querying Access through vba. I agree that our code looks very similar. I just wanted to get an example in here that shows a recordset dropped to a worksheet, manipulated, and then shoved into an array. This is one of those fun examples where there a lots of ways to do what needs to be done : )

Comment: A link about the difference between the two. Looks like they both have some pro's and cons. Might have to use both depending on the project. http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Choosing_between_DAO_and_ADO

Comment: Quite often Recordsets need to be pulled into an Array Framework BEFORE posting to the semi-permanence of a Worksheet because further transformation or manipulation of the Data is needed.  Past Examples, for me, included: Constructing 30,60,90, 120 Aging Buckets for the data returned; Reporting amts from several dozen bank accts into specific Categories; or, creating an Array to report amts based on Timing.  All of this needs to be done BEFORE Worksheet Output.

Comment: @JohnShaw It's been quite a few years since I worked with ADODB recordsets, although I think I still have a couple of workbooks out in the wild in my org. Do you have a solid method for dumping a resultset into an array in VBA? If so, I think it would make a great answer here to this question. I agree it definitely feels wrong to dump to a worksheet range and then manipulate after, I've just never found a better way of converting an `ADODB.resultset` object into an array, collection, or dictionary. I've got to think there is a way to do it without iterating the result set though.

Comment: @JohnShaw I did some digging online and one suggested method for dumping into the array with the `.GetRows()` method of the `ADODB.Recordset` object seemed like it would do the trick. I haven't tested as I'm on a mac today, but it feels like it should work. I've updated the answer to include.

Comment: @JNevill, I've provided my own Answer (DAO) below.  The Procedure instantiates the  Recordset; writes the Recordset into an Array; then, spits it out onto a Worksheet.  The .GetRows() Method works, I believe.  I just found the answer I provided to be a proven way for me.  That's all.

Answer (score 3):

This should work to answer your Question, albeit 5 years late. ***Recordset*** to ***Array*** to ***Worksheet***

**ReDim Preserve** can only be used to resize the upperbound of the last previous dimension. You don't have 1 yet, so no ReDim Preserve.

```
'Goes on Top
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Public Sub Recordset_to_Array_to_Worksheet()

Dim MyArray() As Variant 'unbound Array with no definite dimensions'
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL as String, Fieldname as String
Dim i as Integer, j as Integer, colcnt as Integer, rowcnt as Integer
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Dest as Range

'------------------------RECORDSET------------------------'
Set db = Opendatabase("URL link") 'or Set db = Currentdb()
strSQL = "SQL Statement Here"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strsQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If rst.recordcount <> 0 then '///Do NOT Use "Do While Not rst.EOF" Can cause Problems///'
    colcnt = rst.Fields.Count-1
    rowcnt = rst.recordcount
 Else
    Exit Sub
End IF

'-----------------------------WRITE RECORDSET TO MYARRAY----------------------------'
ReDim MyArray (rowcnt, colcnt) 'Redimension MyArray parameters to fit the SQL returned'
rst.MoveFirst

'Populating Array with Headers from Recordset'
For j = 0 To colcnt
     MyArray(0,j) = rst.Fields(j).name
Next

'Populating Array with Record Data
For i = 1 to rowcnt
    For j = 0 to colcnt
        MyArray(i,j) = rst(j)
    Next J
    rst.movenext
Next i

'---------------------------------WORKSHEET OUTPUT---------------------------------'
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Insert Worksheet Name")
Set Dest = ws.Range("A1") 'Destination Cell
Dest.Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1, UBound(MyArray, 2) + 1).value = 
Application.Transpose(MyArray) 'Resize (secret sauce)

End Sub
```

Comment: Quite often Recordsets need to be pulled into an Array Framework BEFORE posting to the semi-permanence of a Worksheet because further transformation or manipulation of the Data is needed. Past Examples, for me, included: Constructing 30,60,90, 120 Aging Buckets for the data returned; Reporting amts from several dozen bank accts into specific Categories; or, creating an Array to report amts based on Timing. All of this needs to be done BEFORE Worksheet Output.   It was a good question.

Comment: Its nice to see after so many years this question still gets some notice every once and a while. I also love seeing where i was at then and how much ive grown, pretty cool! All though, I dont remember what project I was working on for this LOL

Comment: @DougCoats - I'm with you there.  It feels really good to go back and see just how far you've come.  I don't know you, but I'm proud of you, anyway.

Comment: This is a good addition to the question. It looks like iterating through the recordset object is necessary here to fill the array. I have a suspicion that there is a point where the size of the recordset makes this slower than dumping to the worksheet and then converting the range back into a VBA array to further manipulation. Dumping to a hidden worksheet, converting to array, clearing the background worksheet, and then manipulating may be quicker.

Comment: When i do write vba these days (I dont have to as much as i used too, Im stuck inside sql server mostly now lol), arrays are almost default behavior. In fact, I would say interacting with the object model of the particular application unnecessarily to be a cardinal sin of VBA programming. Though, one thing I didnt quite realize when I originally asked this question was that getrows() transposes the array by default, which I still dont know why (i assume it was to make writing new recordseasier).